# sql query to split a single row value to multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an existing audit table in sql serevr 2010. 
I have the following string in each row :

```
"UserID: 4| GroupID: 1| GroupParentID: 1| GroupType: 1| RevisedBy: 4|"
```

from a row. 
My plan is to create a table of the following format:

```
IDName        IDs
--------      ----------
UserID          4
GroupID         1
GroupParentID   1
GroupType       1
RevisedBy       4
```

Finally I am creating something like this: (referencing the IDs with their master table)

```
IDName        IDs
--------      ----------
UserID          User1
GroupID         Gp1
GroupParentID   GG
GroupType       type1
RevisedBy       User1
```

Hope this makes sense.
please let me know how to achieve this  in high performance as the table has million rows.

thanks

i used a split function to separate the pipes '|'.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML1
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN 
 (  
  SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
      + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
      + '</i>').query('.')
  ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)

);
GO
```

But am getting a table with single column,

```
UserID: 4
GroupID: 1
GroupParentID: 1
GroupType: 1
RevisedBy: 4
```

i am looking for ways to split that.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I have edited my post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing table-valued function above, you could probably write a query something like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (idname,ids)
SELECT substring(item, 1, charindex(':', item) - 1) AS idname
    ,right(item, Len(item) - charindex(':', item) - 1) AS ids
FROM (
    SELECT cf.*
    FROM test t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML1(t.idname, '|') cf
    WHERE item IS NOT NULL
    ) t1;

SELECT *
FROM mytable;
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0e710/8/1)